# Edge traversals of trees

Tags: graphs, trees, graph-traversal

I want to find a minimal vertex in a tree from which we can traverse some edges exactly twice then come back to that vertex then do it with the rest of edges. By minimal, I mean that the difference of numbers of two subsets of edges have to be minimum.

Comment: The problem is probably easy ... but it is poorly stated. In your first graph, starting from vertex 2, you can traverse only one edge at a time out of 4, which is hardly half of them, and the path does not come back to vertex 2 (else it would not be a tree). In the second tree, whether you choose 3 or 4, you have 2 edges on one side and 3 on the other. It is not surprising as it is hard to take one half of an odd number of edges. You must clarify your question.

Comment: Given a vertex $v$ in a tree $T$, let $S_v$ be the set of subtrees formed by deleting $v$ and then adding it back to each component of the resulting forest (i.e., each element of $S_v$ is a subgraph of $T$ induced by $v$ and some component of $T-v$). It sounds like you want to find the vertex $v$ that minimizes $\min_{I\subseteq S_v}\left|\sum_{H\in I}|E(H)| - \sum_{H\in S_v\setminus I}|E(H)|\,\right|$. Is that correct? (The length of your edge traversal of each subtree would be exactly twice its number of edges.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I do not understand your definition. Maybe a notation
standard I do not know. What kind of entities are $H$ and $E$? What is
the definition of $E$? $I$ is an element of $S_v$, and thus is a tree.
But H is defined as an element of $I$ and I am not sure in what way you
consider $I$ to be a set.

Comment: @babou $H$ is an element of $I$, which is a subset of (not element of) $S_v$, which is a set of induced subgraphs of $T$. So the graphs $H$ are induced subgraphs of $T$. For any graph $G$, $E(G)$ refers to the edge set -- that is standard notation.

Comment: HOR2, welcome to CS.SE!  Unfortunately, I'm afraid this question needs a lot of work.  Those noun phrases are far too convoluted; I find them terribly painful to try to follow.  I suggest you try breaking this down into some smaller bite-sized definitions, each building on the previous one, and then use them to give a clearer problem statement.  Also, it would help to include an example, some intuition, the context where you ran into this, and your motivation.  Finally: what have you tried on your own?

Answer (score 1):

For each vertex label each incident edge $e$ with the number of edges reachable through $e$ (including $e$).
The vertex you are looking for satisfies that the maximum of its labels is at most $\left\lceil\frac{n-1}2\right\rceil$. It is easily verified that there is exactly one such vertex in each tree. ($n$ denoes the number of vertices of the tree, thus $n-1$ is the number of edges.)

In order to find that vertex efficiently, we can modify depth first search.

We start at an arbitrary vertex and in each vertex we do the following:

1. Initialize a flag `candidate = true` and an integer `sum = 0`.
2. For each edge $e$ leading to a child $v$:

   1. Call the procedure on $v$. Denote the return value by $s$.
   2. Label the incident end of $e$ with $s$.
   3. `sum = sum + s`.
   4. If $s > \left\lceil\frac{n-1}2\right\rceil$ set `candidate = false`.
3. Set $r = n - 1 - sum$.
4. Label the incident end of the edge leading to the parent with $r$.
5. If $r > \left\lceil\frac{n-1}2\right\rceil$ set `candidate = false`.
6. If `candidate == true` the current vertex is the one we are looking for. Abort.
7. return $r+1$.

The correctness should be straightforward. Since the additional effort is ${\cal O}(1)$ per vertex resp. per outgoing edge, the runtime stays in ${\cal O}(|V| + |E|) = {\cal O}(n)$.

Comment: @HOR2 and how can 2 be an answer in the first graph?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This is a rewriting of the previous version of my answer. It is
hopefully easier to understand. The previous version had a bug in the
vertex labeling formulae where it used $L_v(e)$ instead of $L^v(e)$.*

Since the question was not clear, and changed over time, I present
below a general method that can handle several different definition of
a vertex to be identified by some property. I use it to compute both the
[**Jordan center(s)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_tree) and the
**"gravity" center(s)**.

From the initial statement of the question, and an erased comment made
by the OP, it seemed that the problem was to find the Jordan Center(s)
[there may be two], of the tree. The definition of the Jordan
Center(s) states that it has minimal excentricity, the excentricity of
a vertex being its longest distance to any other vertex. There may be one
or two such vertices in a tree.

The current statement of the question, as clarified by David Richerby,
seems to rather ask how to find what I am calling here the gravity
center of the tree, i.e., a vertex where it can be divided into two
subtrees such that the difference between their number of edges is
minimal.

To simplify the presentation, here are some of the definitions and
notations I am using.

- a tree is a pair composed of a finite non-empty set of vertices (or
  nodes) and a set of unordered pairs of vertices, called edges, such
  that there is exactly one path between any two vertices.
  Our reference tree here is noted $T$.
- an edge is said to be incident on each of its two vertices, and a
  vertex is said incident on all edges it belongs to. A vertex with a
  single incident edge is called a **leaf**.
- a **rooted-tree** is a tree with a distinguished vertex $r$ called the
  root. To specify the root, it may be called a $r$-rooted-tree.
- a **rooted subtree** of a tree $T$ is a rooted-tree such that all
  edges are edges in $T$, and all vertices except possibly the root have
  the same number of incident edges as in $T$. This means that the
  missing parts of $T$ must have been cut off at the root.
- a rooted-tree is **prime** iff there is only one incident edge on
  the root.
- a $u$-rooted subtree $s$ of a $v$-rooted tree $t$ is a **daughter** of
  $t$ iff (v,u) is an edge of $t$. Then, by adding the edge to the
  subtree $s$ you obtain a prime $v$-rooted subtree of $t$.
- $D(t)$ is the set of daughters of a $v$-rooted tree $t$
- $D(v)$ is the set of daughters of the full tree $T$ rooted in vertex $v$.
- $E(t)$ is the set of edges in a (sub)tree $t$. For a vertex $v$,
  $E(v)$ is the set of incident vertices on $v$.
- for a (sub)tree $t$, we call **weight** of $t$ its number of edges.
- an **attribute** (characteristic value) of a rooted tree $t$ is said to
  be **synthesized** if it can be computed from the values of the same
  attribute for the daughters of $t$. The formula to be used to do
  this computation is called the **synthesis formula**. An **initial
  attribute** must be provided for all daughter subtrees that are only a
  single leaf vertex with no edge.
- a **vertex labeling formula** for a tree $T$ is a formula that
  computes a label for each vertex $v$ from attributes computed for
  each daughter of the $v$-rooted tree $T_v$.

Note that the root of a daughter tree always has on less incident edge
in the daughter than in the full tree. The missing edge is precisely
the edge connecting it to the root of its parent tree.

Synthesized attributes can be computed for a $v$-rooted tree $t$ by a
recursive function calling itself recursively on each of the daughters
of $t$.

Alternatively, it can be computed for all daughters of all rooted
subtrees of $T$. There are exactly two such daughters for each edge of
$T$, one at each end of the edge. One proceeds by initializing all the
leaf vertex attributes, and then using the synthesis formula to compute
the attribute for all daughter trees, when their own daughter have had
their attribute computed.  It is easy to show that, as long as there
is a daughter without its attribute, there is one where the attribute
can be computed because it has been done for all its daughters. Hence
the algorithm terminates, with every daughter having its attribute
computed.

Various optimizations are possible, depending on what is being computed.

### Case of the Jordan center.

The attribute needed is the depth $\phi$ of each daughter tree, i.e., the
length of longest path starting from its root.

We initialize the attribute $\phi(l)$ of each leaf daughter $l$ to 0, since
there is no path starting from it.

The **synthesis formula** to compute the attribute for a daughter $d$
is
$\phi(d)= 1+{Max}_{t\in D(d)} \phi(t)$

The vertex labelling formula is then:
 $L(v)=\max_{t\in D(v)} \phi(t)$

The Jordan centers are the vertices with the smallest label.

### Case of the gravity center

We want to  find a vertex $g$ such that the tree can be split at that
vertex (keeping a copy of the vertex in each of the two parts) so that the
weight difference between the two parts is minimal, the weigth of a
tree being the number of edges. I am calling such a vertex a **gravity
center** of the tree (**there may be 2 gravity centers**).

This amounts to finding a vertex $g$ minimizing the weight difference
between the two partitions of a bipartioning of $D(g)$.

For this purpose we choose as attribute the weight $\omega(d)$ of each
daughter tree.

We initialise the attribute $\omega(l)$ of each leaf daughter $l$ to 0, since
it contains no edge.

The **synthesis formula** to compute the attribute for a daughter $d$
is
$\omega(d)=\Sigma_{t\in D(v)} 1+\omega(t)$

Note that, as soon as there is an edge (u,v) such that the two
daughter corresponding to that edge have their weight computed, their
sum is the weight $p=|E(T)|$ of the whole tree $T$. This can then be
used to simplify computation and speed up the algorithm.

The vertex labeling formula label each vertex $v$ with the smallest
weight difference $\delta_v$ between two subtrees partitioned on that
vertex. The vertex with the smallest such value $\delta_v$ is the
answer to the question.  The vertex labelling formula is then:
 $L(v)=\min_{I\subseteq D(v)}\left|\sum_{t\in I}\omega(t) - \sum_{t\in
 D(v)\setminus I}\omega(t)\,\right|$.

Then the gravity center is the vertex with the smallest label.

However, this vertex labeling function is NP complete in the number of
incident edges on the vertex, as it is a [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).  We need a
better way to identifies the center of gravity, without actually
computing the partition into 2 subtrees.

Instead, we identify the gravity center with another property: a
vertex $g$ is a gravity center iff no prime $g$-rooted subtree has more than $(p+1)/2$
edges, where $p=|E(T)|$ is the total number of edges. Hence it is a vertex $g$
with the smallest maximum value for the weight of a prime $g$-rooted subtrees.
Since the weight of a prime $g$-rooted subtree, is just 1 more than
the weight of the corresponding daughter, we can use instead the
weight of daughters.

Thus we use the following vertex labelling formula:
$L(v)=\max_{t\in D(v)} \omega(t)$
Any vertex $g$ with the smallest label $L(g)$ is a gravity center.

**Sketch of a Proof**

First we note there may be one or two gravity centers. For
example, if you connect two trees having the same weight (number of
edges) with an additional edge, then the vertices joined by that edge
are the two gravity center of the larger tree thus created. They both
have a minimum weight difference equal to 1 (corresponding to the
connecting edge). So they both have a prime rooted subtree with
$(p+1)/2$ edges. It is the rooted subtree that start with the connecting
edge.

We note $\delta_v$ the minimum weight difference between subtrees of a bipartition rooted at
the vertex $v$.

Then, we prove that if a prime $v$-rooted subtree $\tau$ has more than
$(p+1)/2$ edges, there is another vertex $u$ such that
$\delta_u<\delta_v$, so that $v$ cannot be a gravity center. The vertex $u$ is the vertex at the other end of the
root vertex of $\tau$. The proof uses the fact that the total weight
of all prime $v$-rooted subtree is constant, equal to $p=|E(T)|$.

We then prove that if a vertex $g$ has a prime $g$-rooted subtree
with exactly $(p+1)/2$ edges, then there is another such vertex, but all
other vertices have a prime $g$-rooted subtree with more edges.

Similarly we prove that if a vertex $g$ has all prime $g$-rooted subtree
with less $(p+1)/2$ edges, all other vertices have a prime
$g$-rooted subtree with more than $(p+1)/2$ edges.

The last 2 proofs are by finite induction on the distance between the
gravity center and the vertex considered. One can show that on a path from a gravity center (that does not include the other, if any), the difference $\delta_v$ associated with a vertex $v$ increases strictly with the distance of $v$ from the gravity center. One can also prove that the maximum weight of a prime $v$-rooted subtree increases strictly too in the same way. This can be used to find quickly the gravity center.

Comment: thanks! but no. i don't want to find jordan center. i was wrong.

Comment: @HOR2 Then can you better explain what you want. Your first example cuts the graph into 4 subgraph. You should say what thye subsets of edges can be in this example. Anyway, as I said, you can use the same technique to compute the center with respect to whatever property of subtrees. You can replace depth of rooted subtrees by their number of edges. You only have to change the propagation formula.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I regret your edit. Yhe problem was poorly stated, and the question was changed after I gave my answer. Both examples given then gave the jordan center as answer, and the OP himself suggested it might be what he was looking for. No I get a downvote because the question was changed under my feet.

Comment: @babou I edited your first paragraph because, whether you intended it or not, it came across as extremely rude to the asker. This is not the first time so please try to be more careful about that. The question changed only by the removal of an example, and, while I agree that the question is somewhat unclear, its meaning didn't change in the edit. So, the Jordan centre was not relevant to the original question, either. If the correct answer to the original example was the Jordan centre (I didn't check), that seems to have been a coincidence.

Comment: You are right! My first explanation was a disaster.

Comment: @DavidRic I checked inadequate in the dictionnary. Indeed it is not exactly what
I meant. My intent was to say "inappropriate", "unfitting" or
"improper", not a matter of clarity but of addressing the right
concept. This is quite frequent with new
users. *I never intend to be rude*. Hence, *your editing was
appropriate*. However the question was indeed swept under my feet, and
an answer including many comments was deleted. So that my answer is
now totally out of context. The fact is that several people did not
understand. And I am still not sure of what is intended. Apparently neither are you.

Comment: @babou OK. I'll assume you didn't intend to be rude in your answers, as long as you assume that any non-technical edits I make to them are because you were rude without intending it! :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Fair enough. And BTW, thanks to the OP for his own comment about his initial question. I think the main problem was that one example should have been worked out in more details, exhibiting clearly what was compared with what.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I'd like to speak in defense of babou a bit here.  To my way of thinking, saying "the presentation is very inadequate" isn't necessarily rude if the presentation is, indeed, very inadequate.  I don't think we need to rebuke babou.  Think of it this way: we have a poorly posed question, but babou still puts all this effort into trying to answer it despite the question being a bit of a mess.  Personally, I think babou deserves some thanks for that.

Comment: @D.W. Note that babou *massively* increased the length of his answer quite some time *after* I edited his language.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well, I was no longer addressing the same problem, and the second one
is somewhat more complex. Also, the first version of my answer was
only intended as hints. Then, trying to explain things about graphs or
trees in words is a mess. Maybe because I do not do it often. Writing
this is a lot more work than I expected, requiring much care to avoid
small errors, and I wonder whether it is read. I must edit it a bit, but I am waiting to see whether there is more to change.

Comment: @HOR2 Here is a new rewritten version of my answer, hopefully in a more readable form. Does it answer the question you had in mind?  Or is it still something else?